# Spring application deployment on Java-ee servers

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Can I deploy a Spring java application on all (or at least most) of JavaEE servers ? like Weblogic, JBoss, Webshpere, Tomcat, Jettty etc.

And is there is preferred Java EE server for Spring ?

Comment: Yes. But you dont need a Java EE compliant server to deploy spring applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. And no - there isn´t. Errata: you can take a look at the [SpringSource dm Server](http://static.springsource.com/projects/dm-server/1.0.x/programmer-guide/html/ch03s02.html). Be aware that spring is not a java EE implementation. Read this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490682/difference-between-java-ee-and-spring-framework).

Comment: Is that possible even on Tomcat ?

Comment: yes of course - nearly all my applications built with spring run on tomcat

Comment: But I heard that Tomcat doesn't implement EJBs, Dependency Injection etc. In that case, wont I have to do some installation of those ?

Comment: The standard Tomcat is not a java EE server. Although there is a EE offspring that is called [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/tomcat-java-ee.html). DI has nothing to do with the application server. Of course you can use that in tomcat. In short words: If you want to use java EE then choose a JEE Application server like JBoss. If not then use tomcat. Be aware that spring is NOT java EE. Read this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490682/difference-between-java-ee-and-spring-framework).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy it on any server, and you can use it on [standalone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106769/create-a-standalone-application-with-maven) and even on [mobile applications](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/). It is in no way restricted to web deployment. It is not even restricted to java, there is [Spring.NET](http://springframework.net) and even a Python version. However, java and web servers are a common if not the most common use for it.

Currently recommended web server by VMWare/Pivotal (current owner of Spring) is [VFabric tcServer](http://www.vmware.com/products/vfabric-tcserver/), which is a Tomcat fork containing some extra tools and functionality. But server in itself does not matter, Spring is container agnostic.

There is no preferred EE server. VFabric tcServer is a servlet container, not an EE server. It contains "[enterprise capabilities](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/vmware-vfabric-tcserver-DS-EN.pdf)" instead, but [that's not the same thing](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/vmware-migrating-JEE-apps-tcServer-technical-WP-EN.pdf). As said however, you can use whichever EE server you want.