# Advantages/disadvantages of deploying a Spring 4 application

Tags: spring, tomcat, webserver, wildfly

What is the best choice for deploying a Spring 4 application?

- Servlet container (e.g. Tomcat)
- Application server (e.g. Wildfly)

I do not like to start a flamewar. Since there is no similar question, I would just like to know the advantages and disadvantages of both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

As a simplification/generalisation, as I understand Spring offers developers much of the functionality of Java EE, but with out the need for a full application server. As a full application server is not essential and a container server such as Tomcat will suffice (more details on the distinction between Spring and Java EE can be found here: [Difference between Java EE and Spring framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490682/difference-between-java-ee-and-spring-framework)) it might be a slightly fairer comparison to consider TomEE as this might have the overhead of a full blown application server if you're considering performance.

This article might be of interest: http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-great-java-application-server-debate-jboss-as7-aka-wildfly/ , although it is a year or two old and compares JBoss 7 to Tomcat. Whilst the article might not be conclusive enough for you the comments might give you some 'food for thought'. The general finding of the article is that if you require performance and support for standards,  and a more aesthetically pleasing administration interface for, then JBoss might might take your fancy.

There is also the following article that will be of interest, but compare a few other options (http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-great-java-application-server-debate-with-tomcat-jboss-glassfish-jetty-and-liberty-profile/).