# Stateful EJB loses its state

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a `ManagedBean` (`SecurityTokenController`) that use a `Stateful SessionBean` (`SecurityTokenClient`).
Each time I call the controller, a new `SecurityTokenClient` bean is instantiated, so I lose the state. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code of the `ManagedBean`:

```
@ManagedBean
public class SecurityTokenController implements Serializable {
  @EJB
  SecurityTokenClient client;

  public String askToken(){
    return client.getToken().toString();
  }
}
```

Here there is the code of the `Stateful SessionBean`:

```
@Stateful
@SessionScoped
public class SecurityTokenClient implements Serializable {
  SecurityToken securityToken;   

  public SecurityTokenVO getToken(){
      if ( null == this.securityToken ) {
          this.securityToken = new SecurityToken();
      }
      return this.securityToken;
  }
}
```

So, every time I call this bean the `securityToken` is `null`. The injected `EJB` is always a different one. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: No scope defined for stateful bean. Maybe you should add @SessionScoped?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I had the same result. So I omitted it. 
I add again.

Comment: I guess your EJB stateful bean is not associated with session automatically. You can use CDI for it I belive. Some more details can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480096/using-a-stateful-session-bean-to-track-an-users-session/8540181#8540181

Comment: How are you calling the Controller? And what is calling the Controller?