# Store data in EJB

Tags: jsf, session, ejb-3.0

I have data of user in my session in `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` in my **BB** but I want store this data in **EJB** that I could get data in any **EJB**. Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Basically [Stateful EJB](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_stateful_beans.htm) is a solution.

More detailed example for your case is here [Using a Stateful Session Bean to track an user's session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480096/using-a-stateful-session-bean-to-track-an-users-session).

I'd suggest improving your "googling" skills :)