# Is it a bad design for a EJB to depend on FacesContext?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

Would it be better, for example, to pass `context.getExternalContext().getRequestLocale()` to the EJB by parameter, instead of using an import and getCurrentInstance from inside the EJB?

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
```

*(I'm new to web development)*

Comment: see [Why is it a good idea for “lower” application layers not to be aware of “higher” ones?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/198783/7460)

Comment: @NathanHughes I'll read (and I think it is a good idea). But is it the context a higher layer? I thing about the context as a side layer that everyone knows about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why shouldn't entity bean be managed by JSF framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431338/why-shouldnt-entity-bean-be-managed-by-jsf-framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think of your software system as a three layer architecture then the `FacesContext` (which is part of the JSF framework) belongs to the presentation layer and the `EJB` to the application layer.

In general it's bad software design when a lower layer (application) depending on higher layer (Presentation). It leads to high coupling, low cohesion and therefore overall to poor software quality.

To sum it up, it would be better to pass the values by parameter instead of accessing the `FacesContext` from a `EJB`.